# swi-prolog: how to sort list of lists by NTH element of sublist, ALLOWING DUPLICATES

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

(I have used 'asserta' to put a large csv file with several columns into the database.) Is there a way to sort numerically by column without removing duplicates?

As you can see from my simple example (which sorts by the second column / element), the predsort method removes duplicates.

I could work around this by switching and removing some columns and using msort, but am asking you specifically here for an alternative.

Any advice would be v much appreciated !

```
mycompare(X,E1,E2):- 
E1=[_,A1],E2=[_,A2],compare(X, A1, A2).

?- predsort(mycompare,[ [[95, 97], 11], [[97, 99], 4], [[97, 98], 4]],X).
X = [[[97, 99], 4], [[95, 97], 11]].

?- msort([ [[95, 97], 11], [[97, 99], 4], [[97, 98], 4]],X).
X = [[[95, 97], 11], [[97, 98], 4], [[97, 99], 4]].

%What I want is:
?- wanted_sort(...<as above>...).
X = [[[97, 98], 4], [[97, 99], 4], [[95, 97], 11] ].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho [predsort](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3)/3 provides a very general and fairly efficient way to do - it's as simple as *avoiding* returning `=` from the comparison predicate. Example:

```
?- [user].
|: comparer(<, A, B) :- A @< B.
|: comparer(>, _, _).
(^D here)
true.

?- predsort(comparer, [1,2,1,a,b,a], L).
L = [1, 1, 2, a, a, b].
```

Your test case:

```
mycompare(<,[_,A1|_],[_,A2|_]) :- A1 < A2.
mycompare(>, _, _).
```

yields

```
?- predsort(mycompare,[ [[95, 97], 11], [[97, 99], 4], [[97, 98], 4]],X).
X = [[[97, 98], 4], [[97, 99], 4], [[95, 97], 11]].
```

I slightly generalized the pattern matched, from `[_,N]` to `[_,N|_]`...

*edit*: it's funny, I didn't read the *title*...
to generalize comparing for nth argument:

```
?- predsort(nthcompare(2),[ [[95, 97], 11], [[97, 99], 4], [[97, 98], 4]],X).
X = [[[97, 98], 4], [[97, 99], 4], [[95, 97], 11]].
```

and nthcompare/4 itself:

```
nthcompare(N,<,A,B) :- nth1(N,A,X),nth1(N,B,Y), X @< Y.
nthcompare(_,>,_,_).
```

that is...

Comment: Your answer says it all for me. Many thanks, @CapelliC

Comment: @Andrew: This solution is not a stable sorting. E.g.: `predsort(mycompare,[[a,1],[b,1]],L).` succeeds with
`L = [[b, 1], [a, 1]].` So you get some more or less random shuffling of elements that are equal.

Comment: @false: to get a stable sorting, should be enough to extend the comparison to include further keys when the primary is equal.

Comment: Right, [like this](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#keysort), but then it's pointless to use predsort/3

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to do this would be to use [`keysort/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#keysort). So first you start by mapping the elements accordingly, then keysorting, and mapping back the values.

```
list_pairs([], []).
list_pairs([E|Es], [B-E|Ps]) :-
   E = [_,B],
   list_pairs(Es, Ps).

pairs_values([], []).
pairs_values([_-V|Ps], [V|Vs]) :-
   pairs_values(Ps, Vs).

andrew_sort(Xs, Ys) :-
   list_pairs(Xs, Ps),
   keysort(Ps, PsS),
   pairs_values(PsS, Ys).
```

For other uses of `keysort/2` see [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[prolog]+keysort).

Comment: Thanks, @false. The code works, and now I finally understand how keysort works. (The swi-prolog manual could do with a few more examples imho).